# Анимация картинки в iOS

Tags: xcode, анимация, cocos2d, objective-c, изображения

Стоит задача сделать анимацию как здесь: http://www.subaru.jp/legacy/b4/index2.html для iPad2. То есть пользователь может слайдить влево и вправо и объект визуально вращается вокруг своей вертикальной оси. Наипростейшее решение представляется так: заполняем массив картинками для анимации и выводим их по тачу в UIImage или CCSprite в cocos2d. Картинки будут 1024х768 и желательно 15-20 кадров в секунду для сохранения плавности анимации. Вопрос: правильное ли это решение с точки зрения производительности, реально ли добиться плавности при таких условиях? Каков предел возможностей данного метода? И если он чересчур низок то как иначе можно решить задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было решено довольно простым методом показанным [здесь:](http://www.imaladec.com/story/animation_uiimageview)